# what does $${}$$::json in Postgres mean?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

`data jsonb NOT NULL DEFAULT $${}$$::jsonb` what does `$${}$$` on table creation? Can't find anything on the internet. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Postgres `$$` (or `$anything$`) is an alternative for a single quotation mark (`'`) to enclose character literals. In other words, `$${}$$` is equivalent to `'{}'`.

It's commonly used to quote strings that themselves might contain single quotation marks, or strings inside dynamic SQL that is already enclosed in single quotes.

[Reference](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING)

Comment: but is there any real reason for that? I mean should I avoid using `'{}'`?